# How to add stream to live channels

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I’m developing a tvml app that has live tv, news and on-demand programs.

Wondering how can I add that to the tv app. I have been looking around but I didn’t seem to find anything...

In tvOS, there is a TV app, with suggestions on shows to watch, Trendings, and sports. Some of those channels like news, and sports, have live content. I am trying to add my live content to the Apple TV app, and not sure what to do.

Btw, I did find the guild for Android TV, 
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/

Answer (score 0):

AppleTV uses Apple's [HTTP Live Stream (HLS)](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).

You should create a server that serves the live stream in .m3u8 with type [`EVENT`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.3.5)

And then in your AppleTV app

```
// create a player
const player = new Player();

// create a playlist
player.playlist = new Playlist();

// create video mediaItem
var video = new MediaItem('video', "https://myserver.example.com/video/live.m3u8");

// add it to the playlist
player.playlist.push(video);

// hit play
player.play();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this is not what I am asking for. In tvOS, there is a TV app, with suggestions on show to watch, Trendings, and sports.. Some of those channels like news, and sports, has content that are live on them.

Comment: So could you try to edit your question and be a bit more specific on what your problem actually is

Comment: sorry I hit enter accidentally up there